# Fastapi soft_time_limit sends auto exception

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, fastapi

I want to terminate tasks that tooks more than a minute. This is my code

```
@celery.task(bind=True, soft_time_limit=60, time_limit=120)
def long_task(self, data: int):
    try:
        for iteration in range(1, data):
            progress = (iteration) / data * 100
            self.update_state(
                state="PROCESS",
                meta={"current": iteration, "total": data, "progress": progress},
            )
            time.sleep(20)
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        progress = (iteration) / data * 100
        self.update_state(
            state="TIMEOUT",
            meta={"current": iteration, "total": data, "progress": progress},
        )
#in here i tried return object but none of them works
```

If sof limit exceeded i want only update state but when i try this code i get an exception
`billiard.exceptions.SoftTimeLimitExceeded: SoftTimeLimitExceeded()` even i tried some custom exceptions but they don't work too

I tried custom exception, i used only return {object something}, i tried raise exception but it's still raise this exception